# Is it possible to mine using Asics on AWS?

Tags: miner-configuration

As title says, I would like to know if mining with asics on aws is possible and how to do it? I don't mean profit because I don't really care and only do it for fun. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS does not offer any ASICs, so no.

ASICs are special machines, with specialized hardware. You would need to physically buy one to use it. Anyone offering any form of cloud mining is trying to scam you.

Comment: Same for FPGA ?

Comment: There are some hosted FPGA options, but nothing that would be able to complete with an ASIC - mining would be a pointless waste of money

Comment: Well, if you have some ressources on it I will gladly take it even if it's a waste of money :)